# Regex Query (Match the 2nd instance prior to a word)

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-lookarounds

I have a random string retrieved from a PDF file. It contains an unstructured table which i have successfully formatted.

However I need to strip out a particular line (which I wont know what it says, but I do know specific words that are contained).

This is an example of the string

> ASSET SCHEDULE\nPolicy Number     1234-567890\nASSET SCHEDULE\nPage 1
> of 4ASSET SCHEDULE\nPolicy Number     1234-567890\nDeal id: 00030
> Policy Number: 1234-567890\nDate: 28-Feb-2023 Policy Currency:
> GBP\nSell transactions\nISIN Asset name Transaction date Deal
> \ntype\nQuantity Price Asset \nCCY\nAsset\nvalue\nExchange rate Policy
> value \nGBP*\nAA00000012 Company 1 01-Mar-2023 SELL 811.7040 13.7556
> GBP 11,165.4755 1.0000 11,143.2600\nAA00000013 Company 2 01-Mar-2023
> SELL 220.0600 10.8200 GBP 2,381.0492 1.0000 2,358.8300\nAA00000014
> Company 3 01-Mar-2023 SELL 16.1250 135.0200 GBP 2,177.1975 1.0000
> 2,154.9200\nAA00000015 Company 4 01-Mar-2023 SELL 4.3420 1,520.7085
> GBP 6,602.9163 1.0000 6,580.1600\nAA00000016 Company 5 01-Mar-2023
> SELL 0.7320 1,878.1622 GBP 1,374.8147 1.0000 1,352.2900\nAA00000017
> Company 6  01-Mar-2023 SELL 106.3298 118.3700 GBP 12,586.2584 1.0000
> 12,564.0400\nAA00000018 Company 7 01-Mar-2023 SELL 109.5476 101.7800
> GBP 11,149.7547 1.0000 11,127.5300\nTotal  GBP : 47,281.03\nBuy
> transactions\nISIN Asset name Transaction date Deal \ntype\nQuantity
> Price Asset \nCCY\nAsset\nvalue\nExchange rate Policy value
> \nGBP*\nAA00000019 Company 8 03-Mar-2023 BUY 42.6400 42.6900 GBP
> 1,820.3016 1.0000 1,842.4400\nAA00000020 Company 9 03-Mar-2023 BUY
> 11.9880 845.6000 GBP 10,137.0528 1.0000 10,159.1700\nAA00000021 Company 10 03-Mar-2023 BUY 6.4120 836.9100 GBP 5,366.2669 1.0000
> 5,388.5200\nAA00000022 Company 11 03-Mar-2023 BUY 205.6830 10.8500 GBP
> 2,231.6606 1.0000 2,253.7800\nAA00000023 Company 12 03-Mar-2023 BUY
> 66.3850 45.4400 GBP 3,016.5344 1.0000 3,038.6500\nP99820\AR/03020/ZZ\n* Policy value amounts may include a
> transaction charge\nASSET SCHEDULE\nPage 2 of 4ASSET SCHEDULE\nPolicy
> Number     1234-567890\nAA00000024 Company 13 03-Mar-2023 BUY 76.7370
> 13.7400 GBP 1,054.3664 1.0000 1,076.4900\nTotal  GBP : 23,759.05\nP99820\AR/03020/ZZ\n* Policy value amounts may include a
> transaction charge\nASSET SCHEDULE\nPage 3 of 4ASSET SCHEDULE\nPolicy
> Number     1234-567890\nDISCLAIMER\nThis document was produced by Once
> CLS S.A. (“Once CLS”) in March 2023. Its\ncontent is intended for
> informational purposes only and is not to be construed as a
> solicitation or an offer\nto buy or sell any life assurance product.
> Neither is the information contained herein intended to\nconstitute
> any form of legal, fiscal or investment advice. It should therefore
> only be used in conjunction\nwith appropriate independent professional
> advice obtained from a suitable and qualified source.\nWhilst every
> care has been taken in producing this document, no representation or
> warranty, whether\nexpress or implied, is made in relation to the
> accuracy, completeness or reliability of the information\ncontained
> herein, except with respect to information concerning Once CLS or its
> group companies.\nAll copyright in this material belongs to Once
> CLS.\nCopyright © 2023 Once CLS S.A.\nOnce CLS S.A.\nASSET
> SCHEDULE\nPage 4 of 4

I want to match from the 2nd `\n` it finds before `\n Policy value` and the `\n` after the Policy number `1234-56789`

so the output for the match would be the following.

```
\nP03929\AB/0002/XX\n Policy value amounts may include a transaction charge\nASSET SCHEDULE\nPage 2 of 4ASSET SCHEDULE\nPolicy Number     1234-56789\n
```

`(00\\n)(.*)(?=Policy value).*(\\n)` matches from the first `00\n` but i need it the first one before the match.

i hope that makes sense.

tried a few different scenarios but cant seem to get it to just find the specific 2nd \n before the match of **Policy value**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex and grab capture group #1:

```bash
00\\n.*?00(\\n(?:(?!00\\n).)*?Policy Number\s+[0-9-]+)\\n
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qEI7av/6)

**RegEx Details:**

- `00`: Match 1st `00`
- `\\n`: Match `\n`
- `.*?`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `00`: Match 2nd `00`
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `\\n`: Match `\n`
  - `(?:(?!00\\n).)`: Match 0 or more of any characters if that is not followed by `00\n`
  - `Policy Number`: Match `Policy Number`
  - `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
  - `[0-9-]+`: Match 1+ pf hyphen or digits
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `\\n`: Match `\n`

Comment: Thanks.. That has worked... however i had made the snippet string shorter.. There's additional text including \n for additional rows and pages.. I literally just want to capture to the end of "\nPolicy Number     1234-56789\n" (so the first \n after Policy Number)..  Thanks again

Comment: Hi, Yes that has worked, however if i add an additional row infront, i get the same issue on the 00\n. so I need only 3 \n before the word Policy value

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the delays, updated the OP with the full text. I can in theory have any number of pages (this particular one is 4 pages). Basically what I'm doing is stripping out each of the rows from a PDF table that isn't actually a PDF. but that string of text can appear on each page. Thanks again

Comment: so if i could, i want to remove the following text from the larger output 

\nP99820\AR/03020/ZZ\n* Policy value amounts may include a transaction charge\nASSET SCHEDULE\nPage 2 of 4ASSET SCHEDULE\nPolicy Number 1234-567890

but if i can match on this, then i can remove it from the larger string seperately

Comment: i get 3 matches for that one, the correct one is Match 3, Group 1.  Is it possible to only have 1 match for my c# coding?

Comment: That works great, just it includes the 00 at the beginning of the line.   00\nP99820\AR/03020/ZZ\n* Policy value amounts may include a transaction charge\nASSET SCHEDULE\nPage 2 of 4ASSET SCHEDULE\nPolicy Number 1234-567890\n . is it possible to ignore that?

Comment: Sure, Check my updated regex and new demo link.

Comment: thanks, fixed that issue but i have asked another question, you might be able to assist with your expertise. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75758634/regex-find-upto-a-first-value-it-finds-before-a-match