# Regex Find Upto a first value it finds before a match

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string value and because of how the string is populated (out of my control) I have \n new line instances right in the middle of a company name.

I wanted to do a regex replace on the particular matches to replace the \n with a space.

This is a snippet of my output (it can change. but all I'm trying to match all occurrences to the first \n it finds before a Date. and extract the text between those.

`\nGBP*\nAA1234567 A random company name - I 03-Mar-2023 BUY 42.6400 42.6900 GBP 1,820.3016 1.0000 1,842.4400\nAA1234568 Another randon company name - H-M 03-Mar-2023 BUY 11.9880 845.6000 GBP 10,137.0528 1.0000 10,159.1700\nAA12345679 Third Party Utilies - Fund - Class\nAA-B Income\n03-Mar-2023 BUY 6.4120 836.9100 GBP 5,366.2669 1.0000 5,388.5200\nAA12345670 Company 4 - M 03-Mar-2023 BUY 205.6830 10.8500 GBP 2,231.6606 1.0000 2,253.7800\nAA2345678 Another random page up company - I 03-Mar-2023 BUY 66.3850 45.4400 GBP 3,016.5344 1.0000 3,038.6500\nASSET SCHEDULE\nPolicy Number     1234-56789\nAA2345679 Company 5 Utilities- M 03-Mar-2023 BUY 76.7370 13.7400 GBP 1,054.3664 1.0000 1,076.4900\nTotal`

Its currently returning.

```
GBP*\nAA1234567 A random company name - I 03-Mar-2023
AA1234568 Another random company name - H-M 03-Mar-2023
AA12345679 Third Party Utilities - Fund - Class\nAA-B Income\n03-Mar-2023
AA12345670 Company 4 - M 03-Mar-2023
AA2345678 Another random page up company - I 03-Mar-2023
ASSET SCHEDULE\nPolicy Number     1234-56789\nAA2345679 Company 5 Utilities- M 03-Mar-2023
```

But what I want to retrieve is the following.

```
AA1234567 A random company name - I 03-Mar-2023 BUY 42.6400 42.6900 GBP 1,820.3016 1.0000 1,842.4400
AA1234568 Another random company name - H-M 03-Mar-2023 BUY 11.9880 845.6000 GBP 10,137.0528 1.0000 10,159.1700
AA12345679 Third Party Utilities - Fund - Class\nAA-B Income\n03-Mar-2023 BUY 6.4120 836.9100 GBP 5,366.2669 1.0000 5,388.5200
AA12345670 Company 4 - M 03-Mar-2023 BUY 205.6830 10.8500 GBP 2,231.6606 1.0000 2,253.7800
AA2345678 Another random page up company - I 03-Mar-2023 BUY 66.3850 45.4400 GBP 3,016.5344 1.0000 3,038.6500
AA2345679 Company 5 Utilities- M 03-Mar-2023 BUY 76.7370 13.7400 GBP 1,054.3664 1.0000 1,076.4900
```

The third row in this occasion contains 2 new lines `Class\nAA-B Income\n`

My Pattern is as follows

```
(?<=\\n).*?([a-zA-Z]{3})-(\d{4})
```

https://regex101.com/r/aiDk9G/1

if there's an easier way please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Tried multiple patterns but cant seem to quite get it.

Comment: Will `(?<=\\n).*?[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}.*?(?=\\n)` work for you as ij https://regex101.com/r/aiDk9G/2

Comment: Hi, that still captures GBP*\n   and then on the last match ASSET SCHEDULE\nPolicy Number     1234-56789\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
(?<=\\n)(?:[A-Z]+[0-9][A-Z0-9]*|-)(?:\s+\w+)+.*?[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}.+?(?=\\n)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aiDk9G/5)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `(?<=\\n)`: Lookbehind to assert presence of `\n` at the previous position
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `[A-Z]+`: Match 1+ of uppercase letters
  - `[0-9]` : Match a digit
  - `[A-Z0-9]*`: Match 0 or more uppercase letters or digits
  - `|` OR
  - `-`: Match a `-`
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `(?:\s+\w+)+`: Match company separated with 1+ whitespaces
- `.*?`: Match 0+ of any character (non-greedy)
- `[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}`: Match `month-year` substring
- `.+?`: Match 1+ of any character (non-greedy)
- `(?=\\n)`: Lookahead to assert presence of `\n` at the next position

Comment: that works for all but the last match which is still including ASSET SCHEDULE\nPolicy Number     1234-56789\n

Comment: Try my updated answer and new demo.

Comment: Yes..!! i think that is it. ill throw it into VS and get back to you. Thanks again

Comment: so little bit of an issue, thats down to me not being clear.  so the XX1234567. could be anything A-Z or digits.. for example \nAA00BKS6F102 Company Name or just a hyphen. \n- Company Name. hope that makes sense

Comment: ok, try my updated answer and new demo.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aiDk9G/5 matches that fine but it does the full row rather than upto the Date

Comment: What do you mean by `full row rather than upto the Date`? In that demo, matches are returning exactly same data you have shown in question or I am missing something?

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. Managed to finish off the final pieces